# Construct a graph using given random paths

Tags: java, graph, tree, binary-tree

Suppose I have an array of Strings that represent paths like {"222/111", "333/222", "444/333", "888/999", "777/999"}. How can I build trees/graphs from the above path items such that I get two graphs:

444,333,222,111 and 888,777,999

(Pseudocode is appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (strings not empty)
    path = strings.pop
    foreach (s:strings)
       if (s starts with path end)
          strings.remove(s)
          path.append(s)
          restart loop
       if (s ends with path start)
          strings.remove(s)
          path.prepend(s)
          restart loop
    paths.add(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should check [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/) project, which also has many graph-based algorithms and sample codes, also it generalize your vertex/edge object representation!